# update value where count is only 1

Tags: mysql

I need to update a value where  another field in that row occurs only one time in the entire table. I have written the following query, but it doesnt work. How do I write this?

Thanks

```
UPDATE debiteuren_afleveradressen 

            SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount
            FROM    debiteuren_afleveradressen
            GROUP BY bedrijf

        SET nummer = 1 WHERE totalCount = 1;
```

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: an sqlfiddle might help

Comment: Using `HAVING totalCount = 1` the select will return only the records needs to be updated

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbf7c/1 created it with only non privacy sensitive content. I need to insert a 1 in number where bedrijf only occurs once. Extra, if bedrijf occurs multiple times, an asc number starting from one. But i can do that manually there arent that many entries yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JOIN` in your `UPDATE` :

```
UPDATE debiteuren_afleveradressen a
JOIN (
    SELECT bedrijf, COUNT(*) as totalCount
    FROM debiteuren_afleveradressen
    GROUP BY bedrijf
) b ON (a.bedrijf = b.bedrijf AND b.totalCount = 1)
SET a.nummer = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess

```
UPDATE debiteuren_afleveradressen 
SET nummer = 1 WHERE bedrijf IN(SELECT bedrijf FROM
(SELECT  bedrijf FROM debiteuren_afleveradressen 
GROUP BY bedrijf HAVING COUNT(*)=1 )as x)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd297/1)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, it gives an error. Maybe the fiddle I posted can help? ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN(SELECT bedrijf FROM (SELECT bedrijf FROM debiteuren_afleveradressen GROUP' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, which is a rather direct translation of what you want:

```
UPDATE debiteuren_afleveradressen
    SET nummer = 1
    WHERE bedrijf in (SELECT bedrijf
                      FROM    debiteuren_afleveradressen
                      GROUP BY bedrijf
                      having count(*) = 1
                     );
```

But, MySQL has a weird limitation, where you have to write that as:

```
UPDATE debiteuren_afleveradressen
    SET nummer = 1
    WHERE bedrijf in (select bedrijf
                      from (SELECT bedrijf
                            FROM    debiteuren_afleveradressen
                            GROUP BY bedrijf
                            having count(*) = 1
                           ) t
                     );
```

MySQL can be a bit inefficient with this type of query.  I would recommend rephrasing it as a `join`:

```
UPDATE debiteuren_afleveradressen join
       (SELECT bedrijf, count(*) as TotalCount
        FROM    debiteuren_afleveradressen
        GROUP BY bedrijf
       ) agg
       on agg.bedrijf = debiteuren_afleveradressen.bedrijf and
          TotalCount = 1
    SET nummer = 1;
```

Comment: It is the same with Oracle and Tsql?

Comment: @Mihai . . . Not at all.  They will also optimize the `in` form correctly (although I think the most recent version of MySQL has improved that problem).